# WebUserControl with file property

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm doing a WebUserControl, and I want to add a property that show a file list in DesingView, like the property ImageUrl on an Image Control, but instead of images, this property accept xml files.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, is so easy : )

```
[UrlProperty]
    public string SourceFile
    {
        get
        {
            //Some Code
            return "";
        }
        set
        {
            //Some Code
        }
    }
```

It's to a generate a FileName property